# why grid cells wont go below 32px width and height?

Tags: javascript, grid

im trying to make static grid with a button that can change number of boxes in it (from 16x16 to 64x64 and anything between). Grid is 40rem x 40rem, when i try to change manually number of boxes in makeGrid() function it works fine up to 20 (boxes change size accordingly), but anything above 20 stays the same size and gets cutoff from my grid. If there is no grid css overflow property stated, grid width change depending on number of boxes but boxes themself won't shrink

my code:

- size button is not working yet, grid size need to be changed mannualy in makeGrid function

```js
const grid = document.getElementById('grid');
const size = document.getElementById('size');
const eraser = document.getElementById('eraser');
const color = document.getElementById('color');
const gridBorder = document.getElementById('grid-borders');
const clear = document.getElementById('clear');

// grid
function makeGrid(number) {
  number = number || 16;
  let cellWidth = 40 / number + 'rem';
  let cellHeight = 40 / number + 'rem';
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat( ${number}, 1fr)`;
  grid.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
  for (let i = 0; i < number * number; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    grid.appendChild(cell).id = 'box';
    cell.classList.add('border');
    cell.classList.add('box');
    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    cell.style.width = cellWidth;
    cell.style.height = cellHeight;
  }
  size.textContent = `${number} x ${number}`;
}
makeGrid();

// drawing on hover
color.addEventListener('click', function () {
  grid.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    e.target !== grid ? (e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black') : null;
  });
});

function changeColor(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

// erase functionality
eraser.addEventListener('click', function () {
  grid.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    e.target !== grid ? (e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white') : null;
  });
});

// grid borders
const allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
gridBorder.addEventListener('click', function () {
  allBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.classList.toggle('no-border');
    box.classList.toggle('border');
  });
});

// clear button
clear.addEventListener('click', function () {
  allBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  });
});

// size button
// size.addEventListener('click', function () {
//   let number = prompt(`Enter grid size less or equal to 100`);
//   if (number !== Number.isInteger()) {
//     return;
//   } else if (number > 100) {
//     number = prompt(`Enter grid size greater or equal to 100`);
//   }
// });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 40rem;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  padding: 1em;
}

#title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 180px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 60%;
  width: 1259px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.border {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.no-border {
  outline: none;
}

.black-bg {
  background: black;
}

.white-bg {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
    </div>
    <main id="container">
      <div id="menu">
        <button id="size"></button>
        <button id="color">Color</button>
        <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        <button id="grid-borders">Grid Borders</button>
      </div>

      <div id="grid"></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Why won't my grid cells go below 32px?" - have you checked your padding (hint: 32px is exactly equal to 2 * 16px which in turn is exactly equal to your padding of 1em with most browsers implementing a default font-size of 16px). –
David Thomas

box padding was set to 1em which caused my problem, after deleting it my grid worked as intended

Comment: I appreciate the citation (genuinely!), but you'd be better off explaining that it was due to your `font-size`; and that changing that `font-size` (presumably) helped.

Comment: Using comments is a much better way when you dont have any answer for the question. If you have additional information about the original question, please use edit function.